# How do I format this SQL Like Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone assist with this syntax

```
   sum((case when isnull(lpc.sales_part_code,'') like 'E%' 
             then 1 else 0 end) as e_line_count
             then 1 else 0 end) as e_line_count
    from sales_order_lines_with_rollup sol    
    inner join edap_dw.fact_sales_order_header soh
    on sol.business_unit_key = soh.business_unit_key
    and sol.sales_order_number = soh.sales_order_number
    left join edap_dw.fact_inventory_on_hand_warehouse w
    on sol.part_key = w.part_key
    and w.snapshot_day_key = sol.order_date_key
    left join edap_dw.dim_part_code lpc 
    on sol.part_key = lpc.part_key and lpc.current_record_ind = 'Y'
    LEFT JOIN #business_days do ON do.time_day_key = sol.order_date_key
    LEFT JOIN #business_days ds ON ds.time_day_key = case when sol.ship_day_key = -1 then format(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') else sol.ship_day_key end
    --LEFT JOIN #business_days dp ON dp.time_day_key = case when sol.promised_ship_day_key = -1 then format(GETDATE(),'yyyyMMdd') else sol.promised_ship_day_key end
    where sol.sales_order_quantity > 0
    and sol.order_date_key > 20170101
    group by sol.sales_order_number,sol.business_unit_key
```

I need to add another code '%-1%' to the like clause in this section:

```
sum((case when isnull(lpc.sales_part_code,'') like 'E%' 
             then 1 else 0 end) as e_line_count
             then 1 else 0 end) as e_line_count
```

so it should look something like

```
sum((case when isnull(lpc.sales_part_code,'') like 'E%' or when isnull(lpc.sales_part_code,'') = '-1%'
             then 1 else 0 end) as e_line_count
             then 1 else 0 end) as e_line_count
```

I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: Just change `like 'E%' or when isnull` to `like 'E%' or isnull` - each branch of a `CASE` expression can only have a single `WHEN`. (Also presumably you want the second expression to use `LIKE` and not `=`.)

Comment: like this?  sum((case when isnull(lpc.sales_part_code,'') like 'E%' or isnull(lpc.sales_part_code,'') like '-1%'

Comment: Also, you don't need `ISNULL()` in there. `SUM(CASE WHEN lpc.sales_part_code LIKE 'E%' OR lpc.sales_part_code LIKE '-1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS e_line_count`. Don't ask "like this?" Try it.

Comment: On a separate note, good use of whitespace and linebreaks is really important. All left aligned code is very difficult to work out where one section of code ends and another begins.

Comment: A SQL (select) statement usually starts with `SELECT`....

Comment: And decide on a consistent casing approach and stick to it... along with whitespace and linebreaks this will all make your queries much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted the 2nd evaluation to be a LIKE operator and not equals

```
SUM(case when lpc.sales_part_code LIKE 'E%' or lpc.sales_part_code LIKE '-1%' then 1 else 0 end)
```